# Token is coming as null from GetTokenAsync in Blazor Server

Tags: .net-core, jwt, blazor-server-side, bearer-token

I have created a blazor server app(.NET6) and I have used JWT authentication to authenticate the app with referring this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0) . when going to get a token that is saved in the local storage, I'm getting a null value.

my program.cs

```
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
                       ...
    
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
            builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<TokenProvider>();
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        
        
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                         {
                             options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                             options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                             options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                         })
                        .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, x =>
                         {
                             x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                             x.SaveToken = true;
                         });


   if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    ...
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    
    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.MapBlazorHub();
    app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    
    app.Run();
```

TokenProvider.cs

```
public class TokenProvider
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

InitialApplicationState.cs

```
public class InitialApplicationState
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

Pages/_Host.cshtml file ,

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication

...

@{
    var tokens = new InitialApplicationState
    {
        AccessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token"),
        RefreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token")
    };
}

<component type="typeof(App)" param-InitialState="tokens" 
    render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

I am getting this  AccessToken and RefreshToken as null above code

App.razor

```
    @inject TokenProvider TokenProvider

...

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public InitialApplicationState InitialState { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        TokenProvider.AccessToken = InitialState.AccessToken;
        TokenProvider.RefreshToken = InitialState.RefreshToken;

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

in here I am setting tokenprovider token values, but it is being set as null values, because of InitialState tokens are null
so I need to know why does this happen??,where I am wrong?? please help me

Answer (score 1):

I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect package.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie().AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.Authority = GlobalConstants.IDENTITY_SERVER_URL;
    options.ClientId = GlobalConstants.IDENTITY_SERVER_CLIENT;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    /// Set here ClientSecret ResponseType and add scopes
}
```

It's working for me, successfully retrieve an access token.